# How to stack divs to fit the entire width and height

Tags: html, css

I want to emulate the Iphone Gallery, I am stacking div's correctly with flexbox, but with different widths and heights, and they don’t stack properly. Here is a screenshot since the code is so big:

[image]

I tried as shown in the photo, I can't get the div's to fill all the page. Here is an Iphone image that I want to do:

[image]

Here's an example:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: red;
}

.photo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid white;
}

.photo.big {
    width: 150px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo big"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example

```css
#container {
    display: grid;
    
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background-color: red;
}

.photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid white;
}

.photo.big {

    grid-column-start:2;
    grid-column-end: span 2;
    grid-row-start:2;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
    
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2.5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo big"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
        <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with grid layout. If you don’t know about it, here is the link I used to learn grid layout in css:
https://cssgridgarden.com/